# Use docker-compose to push application in Dokku in Digital Ocean

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a dockerized flask application with 2 services inside docker-compose. How can I use docker-compose to push my application inside of Dokku on Digital Ocean?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: ad
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"

  scheduler:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./config.ini:/etc/ofelia/config.ini
    depends_on:
      - web
```

I have setup and configured a Dokku droplet. Any help is appreciated.

Resources -

- https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/builders/dockerfiles/
- https://auth0.com/blog/hosting-applications-using-digitalocean-and-dokku/
- https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/deploy-a-flask-application-with-dokku/